# The x-intercept of k is 0.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions, slope

The x-intercept of a line K is ZERO means?

Does this also mans this line

[image]

Does the line shown in orange which is parallel to X axis also qualifies a line whose X intercept is 0? Because this line is also not intercepting the X axis anywhere?

Comment: The orange line has no $x$-intercept. Any line parallel to the $x$-axis, which is not itself the $x$-axis, has no $x$-intercept.

Comment: You mean infinite X intercept?

Comment: No, I mean that the orange line has no $x$-intercept.

Comment: The line definitely does NOT intercept with X at $0$.

Comment: But theoretically I think it has infinite Intercept.

Comment: No. It doesn't. I'm preparing an answer as we speak.

Comment: The line $y=0$ (i.e. the $x$-axis itself) is the only line in $\Bbb R^2$ which would be considered to have "infinite $x$-intercepts".

Comment: [Official GMAT question](https://gmatclub.com/forum/in-the-xy-plane-is-the-slope-of-line-k-equal-to-146084.html) OA: E, but few experts says its A and the official answer is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A line with an $x$-intercept of zero means that it crosses the $x$ axis at the point $(0, 0)$. Recall that $x$-intercepts are those points of the form $(x, 0)$.

Now, consider the line $y = k$ for nonzero $k$. This line is parallel to the $x$ axis (and thus has slope zero) but only contains points of the form $(x, k)$ where $k$ is fixed. Drawing a picture shows that it does not cross the $x$-axis and so there are no $x$-intercepts. Not infinitely many $x$-intercepts. No $x$-intercepts.

TLDR: If it doesn't cross the $x$-axis then there are no $x$-intercepts.

Answer (score 1):

$x$ intercept of a line is generally the distance from the origin at which the line cuts $x$ axis. In your case the orange line never cuts/intersect $x$ axis so there is no $x$ intercept